# Why is the C1 capacitor used in this circuit?

Tags: capacitor

In the circuit attached, there is the C1 capacitor. Why is it there in the circuit?

[image: Text]

Answer (score 4):

The [VS1838B](https://www.elecrow.com/download/Infrared%20receiver%20vs1838b.pdf) has an open-collector output with an unspecified value of pullup resistor.

[image]

The capacitor (in conjunction with the internal resistor) forms a kind of pulse-stretching circuit so the LED remains off for longer than it would otherwise, presumably so it is easier (or possible) to see visually. The transistor discharges the capacitor quickly (turning the LED off) and then it relatively slowly charges up through the resistor to sufficient voltage to turn the LED back on.

It's a bit of a hack, and the time and the maximum current through the output transistor are poorly defined so it may or may not be very reliable or work well with every VS1838B unit.

Comment: It is a Chinese copy of the old Siliconix (now Vishay) TSOP1838 which is obsolete now.

Comment: @Audioguru If they copied it faithfully, the pullup is nominally 30kΩ (no min/max given), so it would stretch the pulse by about 0.1RC or 0.15 second. Reasonable enough. P.S. and from .. Telefunken. Haven't heard that name in a long while.

Answer (score 1):

The IR receiver part is used incorrectly and the capacitor should really not be there. It is very likely a too high current load for the IR receiver output for proper long-term operation.

But, if we ignore that this circuit is bad and should not exist, the capacitor is there to extend the low output pulse from the IR receiver, so that for any short burst of IR signal is detected by the receiver, it will discharge the capacitor and turn the transistor and LED off for some rather unknown length of time, until the low pulses stop and a weak pull-up again charges the capacitor and turns the transistor and LED on.